# AXUPLOADER - Insert file names into MySQL database on successful upload

Tags: php, mysql

I am using AXUPLOADER that I found **[here](http://www.albanx.com/?pid=1&subid=1)**. I want to insert filenames into MySQL table (using mysql `INSERT INTO` methord for each file so that each file creates its row in the table) on successful upload.

I made a SQL insert php file, `insert.php`, and included it in `upload.php` file bundled with the package which handles file uploads, and works fine in my Windows Vista PC running PHP5 and MySQL 5.5.8 with Apache 2. But when I did it in a Windows 7 PC with same server environment, the php file is inserting a row for **each MB**!!

That is, suppose if I upload a file with a size of 1.8MB, two rows will be created with same data and 5 rows for 4.8 MB and so on. If i upload 5 files with 4MB size (total 20MB), 40 rows will be inserted!.

The modified `upload.php` file is lengthy, so that I cant paste it here in Stack Overflow. **[HERE](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/566534/)** is the script.

It will be helpful if somebody give me a solution. More details will be provided if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because it upload files by chunks of 1 mb, that's why you get many inserts